# How can I use babel to transpile SVGs into React components?

Tags: reactjs, svg, babeljs

I am using [Create React App](https://github.com/facebook/create-react-app) to build a component library. In some of my components, I import SVGs like this:

```
import { ReactComponent as IconClear } from 'icons/clear.svg';
```

This works in development, as I know CRA has support for SVGs like this.

I am using `@babel/cli` to transpile my `src/lib` folder into a `dist` folder to use the library as a node package:

```
rm -rf dist && NODE_ENV=production babel src/lib --out-dir dist --copy-files
```

In production, these SVG components don't work. I get the error:

> Error: Element type is invalid: expected a string (for built-in components) or a class/function (for composite components) but got: undefined.

How can I use babel to transpile these SVGs into components? I don't want to manually have to create components for each SVG and I want to keep the SVG markup intact, so it can still be opened in design software. Is there a babel preset / plugin that can do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was able to accomplish what I needed using the [babel-plugin-inline-react-svg](https://www.npmjs.com/package/babel-plugin-inline-react-svg) package.

I simply installed it:
`npm install babel-plugin-inline-react-svg --save-dev`

Then I added it as a `plugin` in my **babel.config.json**.

```
"plugins": ["inline-react-svg"]
```

Now when I run my `build` script, the SVGs are inlined.

The source code:

```
import { ReactComponent as IconClear } from 'icons/clear.svg';
```

...is transpiled into:

```
var IconClear = function IconClear(props) {
  return /*#__PURE__*/_react.default.createElement("svg", props, /*#__PURE__*/_react.default.createElement("path", {
    d: "M12.59 0 14 1.41 8.41 7 14 12.59 12.59 14 7 8.41 1.41 14 0 12.59 5.59 7 0 1.41 1.41 0 7 5.59z"
  }));
};
```

SVGs now work in production without any errors.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like [this package](https://www.npmjs.com/package/@svgr/babel-plugin-transform-svg-component) from NPM does exactly what you're looking for, as denoted at the bottom of the relevant [SVGR documentation](https://react-svgr.com/docs/custom-transformations/) (what CRA uses)

Comment: This looks promising but after adding the plugin and running my `build` script, I get this error: `Cannot read property 'componentName' of undefined`.

Comment: @MichaelLynch it looks like it's [not supported yet](https://github.com/gregberge/svgr/issues/512#issuecomment-927289509). Maybe you'll have better luck with [this package](https://www.npmjs.com/package/@dr.pogodin/babel-preset-svgr) which is listed lower in the same thread.

Comment: It looks like [@dr.pogodin/babel-preset-svgr](https://www.npmjs.com/package/@dr.pogodin/babel-preset-svgr) requires webpack configuration, but unfortunately you can't configure webpack when using Create React App, at least, not without ejecting.